# General C++ Performance Improvement Tips

Tags: c++

Could someone point me to an article, or write some tips right here about some C++ programming habits that are generally valid (no real drawbacks) and improves performance?  I do not mean programming patterns and algorithm complexity - I need small things like how you define your functions, things to do/to avoid in loops, what to allocate on the stack, what on the heap, and so on.

It's not about making a particular software faster, also it's not about how to create a clean software design, but rather programming habits that - if you always apply them, you will make your code rather a little bit faster than a little bit slower.

Comment: I have some programming habits of optimization built up over the years (from assembly language & 8-bit micros).  The issue is that often times, a simple change in design will make the *{micro}* optimizations null and void.  My best optimization is to reduce {refrain from} the coding of unnecessary methods and objects.  There will always be time to add more functionality, if necessary.

Comment: With most languages, especially one as complicated as C++ if you're not doing something grossly incompetent (like copying huge chunks of data every time through a loop) it is nearly impossible to determine what if any effect "design-time" optimization has - including these little habits. My advice is that of [Steve McConnell's] (http://www.stevemcconnell.com/): it is simply not worth worrying about optimization when coding. Make it a habit to write __readable__ code instead of __optimized__ code.

Comment: but if you're writing realtime application, linear time matters too, and over the development of an application the bottleneck can shift to another place - and if you coded there carefully before, things might run faster

Comment: What's the real question here?  The best I can decipher from the text is extremely broad and self-contradictory (general advice on performance but not algorithmic complexity and then some segue into general programming habits that only have "a little bit" of a performance impact?).

Comment: exactly :) i'm just looking for habits that for sure won't hurt, but COULD make code a little bit better

Comment: @Matt: I do not agree with you. You can write optimized and readable at the same time. You shouldn't be trying to optimized everything, but at least optimized what you already know that could be.

Comment: You might interested in my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/653980/c-optimization-techniques/3928544#3928544

Comment: @RogerPate The question is about general things that speed up code execution beyond the bromide of using more efficient algorithms and profiling. Sometimes, a person is just interested in the topic of efficiency for its own sake. The question is quite clear although it isn't focused.

Answer (score 38):

A number of the tips in [Effective C++](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201924889), [More Effective C++](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/020163371X), [Effective STL](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201749629) and [C++ Coding Standards](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321113586) are along this line.

A simple example of such a tip: use preincrement (++i) rather than postincrement (i++) when possible. This is especially important with iterators, as postincrement involves copying the iterator. You optimizer *may* be able to undo this, but it isn't any extra work to write preincrement instead, so why take the risk?

Comment: I've heard some refer to the practice of writing less efficient code that isn't any easier to read/write as "premature pessimization".

Comment: I'm not sure why so many people recommend preincrementing for optimization. It's simple, sure, but it's also a microoptimization that only becomes noticeable if you are doing huge amounts of looping.

The other downside to preincrementing is that it can also occasionally lead to logic errors in expressions that are difficult to find because they would not generate an error or a warning.

Comment: I use it not because it's faster, but because I find it more expressive. "Increment i" is written "++i". Postincrementing is just as likely to lead to logic errors as preincrementing - the problem is if you use the wrong one, you get the wrong answer.

Comment: that's exactly the type of tips i meant - thanks for that. I didn't know about this yet - and since it doesn't hurt to write ++i instead of i++ as long as it's logically correct i try to make this a habit

Comment: This tip cannot be overemphasized enough. In my 'for' loops, I used to use i++. After some thought, I said to myself, "Self, does this not add overhead by creating a temporary int?" And of course, you can guess my answer to myself.

Comment: @George, actually, for primitive types I believe it is guaranteed not to create a temporary.  Even if it isn't guaranteed by the standard, in practice every compiler you're likely to encounter will make the optimization for primitives (it's merely a matter of where it puts the increment instruction in the output machine code)

Comment: I personally HATE seeing ++i. For me, I like seeing the object that is being modified to the left of the operator modifying it. On modern compilers it's going to make no difference in any case.

Comment: @George as rmeador says primitives does not create a copy when using postincrement/decrement over pre. Generally if you are in doubt, try looking at the assembly the compiler generate, it should help answering your question. Further more, the compiler is an extremely advanced tool created by some of the people who know the most about the language and optimizations, trust that it can optimize simple things like this.

Comment: Compilers can optimize `i++` to be just as efficient as `++i` for primitives, but not for iterators, and consistency is good.

Comment: @BillyONeal, try reading pre-increment like `++i` this way: "increment i", then compare it to the `i++`: "i increment". Which sounds more adequate? Hope now you hate that form of increment less. :)

Comment: I use pre-increment in C++ in these types of for loops (for various reasons, consistency with what others expect actually being more relevant than the tiny/negligible performance difference); however, I think how Go makes it post-fix and a *statement* (therefore, no need for the pointless debate *and* get the better syntax) is an interesting take on the matter.

Comment: Well, I'd say no need for debate and you get the worse syntax, but yes, if it's not an expression then there's no performance issue to argue about. Likewise in x86 assembler it's `inc eax`, which is also a "statement" not an expression ;-)

Comment: @Roger Pate:  Lots of problems in C and related languages would have been avoided by making certain constructs into statements - specifically, anything that alters a value.

Comment: @David Thornley: agreed. It wouldn't surprise me if 90% or more C/C++ programmers aren't even aware of the concept of "sequence points", which suggests that it was a bad idea to make side-effects in expressions so prevalent. I remember when I used to read comp.lang.c (way back when) one of the most common questions was "what does i = i++ mean?". I swear that some variant of that was asked at least once per week. (The answer is that it's undefined as i is being mutated twice with no intervening sequence point.)

Comment: Steve: True, better is subjective, but `eggs->and.bacon(are).yummy[3]->food++` is considerably more obvious for me. -- Laurence: my understanding is sequence points are disappearing in 0x in favor of "is-sequenced-before" semantics, to throw another wrench in the works.

Comment: Why didn't they call it ++C hehehe :D

Comment: @Roger: OK, although if I was using pre-increment with that I'd always put in the unnecessary brackets anyway: `++(eggs ... food)`, which I think makes it obvious. If you can't remember what you're doing from one end of a code line to the other, the code lines are too long, and your example is deliberately borderline even without an increment. @Partial: on those grounds it should be called (C+1). It doesn't modify C every time you use C++ ;-)

Comment: The problem with tips like 'use ++i' is that they enter into the folklore and tend to stay there forever, even though compiler optimization may have rendered the tip obsolete. I recommend 'Compiler Explorer' to see what modern compilers do and to weed out such folklore. I would expect no difference for increments used for loop induction variables, which is one of the most common cases.

Comment: @PaulFloyd I see this resistance often, but it makes no sense. For one, it's the exact same effort to write either one. Secondly, it could be faster, especially for larger objects. Thirdly, it semantically makes more sense as post-increment conveys to someone reading your code that you intend to use the previous value. If you don't intend to do that, use the prefix-increment.

Answer (score 33):

If I understand you correctly, you're asking about avoiding **Premature Pessimization**, a good complement to avoiding Premature Optimization.  The #1 thing to avoid, based on my experience, is to not copy large objects whenever possible.  This includes:

- pass objects by (const) reference to functions
- return objects by (const) reference whenever practical
- make sure you declare a reference variable when you need it

This last bullet requires some explanation.  I can't tell you how many times I've seen this:

```
class Foo
{
    const BigObject & bar();
};

// ... somewhere in code ...
BigObject obj = foo.bar();  // OOPS!  This creates a copy!
```

The right way is:

```
const BigOject &obj = foo.bar();  // does not create a copy
```

These guidelines apply to anything larger than a smart pointer or a built-in type.  Also, I highly recommend investing time learning to **profile your code**.  A good profiling tool will help catch wasteful operations.

Comment: Have you heard of copy elision?

Comment: so what's the right way to do it without creating a copy? (in your example)

Comment: @Inverse: I've heard of it, but I wouldn't expect it to happen between compilation units.

Comment: @Mike: RVO doesn't require inlining (after all, it's semantically equivalent to passing a pointer to target location from the caller, and doing a placement new on that in the callee), and thus isn't in any way affected by translation unit boundaries.

Comment: @genesys, the right way is to not declare an object when you only need the reference.  It's a simple oversight but it adds up fast when it shows up in frequently called code.

Comment: @genesys: just turn obj to a reference. Deciding whether to use a reference or not depeands only if you need to modify the object that bar() is returning or you just need to see the state of BigObject.
If you only need read permissions make sure the reference is **const**.  If you need to modifiy a copy of what's bar() returning don't use a reference.

Comment: why is it necessary to make sure the reference is const?

Comment: I would read (http://cpp-next.com/archive/2009/08/want-speed-pass-by-value/) and think about why and when you might want to use copy semantics instead of blinding prescribing `const&` everywhere.

Comment: @D.Shawley, I like the recommendation to pass by value when you would otherwise make a copy of a function argument.  However, I still maintain that using `const &` when practical is a good starting point for most people.  The average C++ programmer doesn't know about copy elision and RVO, and IMHO it's easier to get those wrong than it is to forget to use references.

Comment: @genesys, the references don't have to be `const`.  It's just that they ususally are, so that's how I chose to write the example code.  Since you mentioned real-time code, I would place bigger emphasis on **profiling** than worrying about the language lawering going on in the comments here.

Comment: of course - i don't hope to get any significant performance increase of applying any of those tips. i just think a serious programmer should - where ever it has no drawback - write code in the most performant way possible

Comment: Just be careful about returning a reference as it introduces a class of bugs: Returning a reference to an object that is destroyed such as a local variable. For example `int const& f() { return 5; }` will silently cause havoc in your code although you might get a warning during compilation.

Answer (score 19):

A few of my pet peeves:

1. Don't declare (actually, define) object variables before their use/initialization (as in C).  This necessitates that the constructor AND assigment operator functions will run, and for complex objects, could be costly.
2. Prefer pre-increment to post-increment.  This will only matter for iterators and user-defined types with overloaded operators.
3. Use the smallest primitive types possible.  Don't use a long int to store a value in the range 0..5.  This will reduce overall memory usage, improving locality and thus overall performance.
4. Use heap memory (dynamic allocation) only when necessary.  Many C++ programmers use the heap by default.  Dynamic allocations and deallocations are expensive.
5. Minimize the use of temporaries (particularly with string-based processing).  Stroustrup presents a good technique for defining the logical equivalent of ternary and higher-order arithmetic operators in "The C++ Programming Language."
6. Know your compiler/linker options.  Also know which ones cause non-standard behavior.  These dramatically affect runtime performance.
7. Know the performance/functionality tradeoffs of the STL containers (e.g., don't frequently insert into a vector, use a list).
8. Don't initialize variables, objects, containers, etc., when they are going to be unconditionally assigned to.
9. Consider the order of evaluation of compound conditionals.  E.g., given `if (a && b)`, if b is more likely to be false, place it first to save the evaluation of a.

There are many other "bad habits" which I won't mention, because in practice, modern compilers/optimizers will eliminate the ill effects (for example, return value optimization vs. pass-by-reference, loop unwinding, etc.).

Comment: I disagree with #8 on the grounds of software maintenance.  Just because something was originally unconditionally assigned to doesn't mean it always will be.  For the vast majority of cases, initializing your variables is a very good idea.

Comment: I disagree with #3.  If a processor's native word is 32 bits, it is optimized to handle 32 bits; whether you use all of them or less.  Some processors may choke or gag when trying to access variables of less size.  For example, an ARM processor in 8 | 32 bit mode (8-bit chars, 32 bit integers) has a hard time with 16-bit quantities.  So a short int (16 bits) actually may slow down the processor compared to an int (32-bits).  Use integers and only short's when necessary.

Comment: I can't speak to ARM processors, but on x86s, you'll only run into a problem like that if your variable spans a word boundary in memory.  This is more likely to happen when you use variables that aren't the word size.  Of course, most compilers will align variables in memory to the word size, thus avoiding the issue (and potentially using the same amount of memory as it would have if you'd just used word-sized variables in the first place).

Comment: +1 for mostly good advice, though I also disagree with #3. Although you'll need to go back in time at least 10 years to find an ARM that doesn't handle 16-bit quantities.

Comment: @Mike: But all arithmatic is done on int size objects. So anything that is smaller needs to be converted into an int. Normally I would not expect a major (or any) hit because of this but on soome systems this may take 2 instructions rather than one to load a value and seat it correctly because of memory alignment (ie registers can only read 32 bit quantities aligned to 32 bit boundries, thus loading an 16 bit value aligned to a 16 bit boundry is a load followed by a shift. Yes rare but a potential. Thus unless you have real specific situaion prefer int for normal/small range numbers.

Comment: @Martin: you're right - that's why I disagree with #3.

Comment: for #8, maybe provide an copy-constructor for that class and initialize that object usint the copy-constructor, so assigng the object wont be necessary.

Additionally your hint #8 infringes the RAII paradigm.

Comment: #3 is just wrong. In almost every case, smaller units than ints are going to hurt performance. Otherwise, good list.

Comment: My motivation for #3:
I've worked with data-intensive applications where every floating point value was stored as a double regardless of its possible magnitude.  In this case, I suppose two memory reads would be necessary to get a 64-bit double, where a 32-bit float would have sufficed.  My primary concern was overall run-time memory usage/footprint.  Even in the integer case, and I understand the counter-arguments, if the arithmetic operations on these values are seldom, the savings on page faults would far outweigh the extra arithmetic instructions.

Comment: @luke: since the OP asked about overall performance considerations, I'm assuming that performance is somewhat important.  Most any practice that increases performance will in some way hurt one of the other -ilities.  I tend to lean against making concessions for amateur programmers.  You shouldn't be modifying any use of a variable that could leave it unitialized without first confirming whether that would be incorrect.

Comment: @user123456 Sorry for the very late comment after several years, but I happened to work on a project were using float values on the critical path was much slower than using doubles. The operation was basically a multiplication of two 24bit floats and could be vectorized, so I expected a nice speed-up because one SSE operation can process more floats than doubles. However, the compiler injects conversion operations from internal floating point to float which were not needed when using doubles. This highlights that if you care about performance you need to measure.

Comment: @jalf I'm not so sure that's true. C++ intentionally leaves the actual precision of these types implementation defined with the only requirement being the minimum max and maximum min they can hold and their relationship between each other (such as `sizeof(int) >= sizeof(short)`). The implementation will most likely use the quickest option. If you really want speed, you can look into the types such as `int_fast8_t` that specify the size needed while welcoming the fastest option to achieve it.

Answer (score 16):

The "[Optimizing Software in C++](http://agner.org/optimize/optimizing_cpp.pdf)" by [Agner Fog](http://www.agner.org) is generally one of the best references for optimization techniques both simple, but definitely also more advanced. One other great advantage is that it is free to read on his website. (See link in his name for his website, and link on paper title for pdf).

**Edit:** Also remember that 90% (or more) of the time is spent in 10% (or less) of the code. So in general optimizing code is really about pinpointing your bottlenecks. Further more it is important and useful to know that modern compilers will do optimzation much better than most coders, especially micro optimizations such as delaying initialization of variables, etc. The compilers are often extremely good at optimizing, so spend your time writing stable, reliable and simple code.

I'd argue that it pays to focus more on the choice of algorithm than on micro optimizations, at least for the most part.

Comment: From my experience, more effort should be spent in a program's correctness and robustness than performance.  A high performance program that often locks up or crashes is of little value compared to a slower program that rarely locks up or crashes.

Comment: You should aspire to both correctness and high performance.  People always pit the two against each other as if you can't have both, but you can and should.

Comment: @Dan I completely agree with you. But I've seen lots of code where people in good faith have tried to optimize the code, and where the only result has been making it more difficult for the compiler to optimize the code. I think the one place where you can really boost your programs performance, is through choosing your design and algorithm carefully. Of course a profiler is needed to identify those 10% code that takes the 90%, and to find out if it can be optimized further (and how).

Comment: Your program should be adequately correct (if it's completely correct, it's either way expensive or trivial).  It should have enough performance on what your target audience would consider a low-end system.  You should have the wisdom not to mess up things for the compiler.

Comment: I love Agner Fog's writing, but a lot of it is processor-dependent. It's not always helpful if your program has to run on many kinds of processor.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews The question was about risk free optimizations that are a good habit. It wasn't about how correct input/output relationships with robustness and stability are important... I mean, we all know correct software that doesn't crash and can be changed is a good thing.

Answer (score 15):

One of the good starting points is the [Sutter's Guru of the week](http://gotw.ca/publications/index.htm) series, and the *Exceptional C++* books that grew out of that.

Answer (score 12):

Use functors (classes with `operator()` implemented) instead of function pointers. The compiler has an easier job inlining the former. That's why C++'s `std::sort` tends to perform better (when given a functor) than C's `qsort`.

Comment: `std::sort` to a large extent also does better because it can also avoid the need for extra indirection (passing addresses of two objects being compared as `void*`, rather than objects themselves, even where a plain copy is cheaper).

Comment: @PavelMinaev That's what Fred said. The comparator can be inlined, avoiding the function call. Less indirection. Have you profiled passing a small chunk of memory, perhaps an `int`, versus passing a reference to it? I'd predict the two are equal in speed. I benchmarked it, and the results were the same.

Answer (score 9):

It seems from your question that you already know about the "premature optimization is evil" philosophy, so I won't preach about that. :)

Modern compilers are already pretty smart at micro-optimizing things for you. If you try too hard, you can often make things slower than the original straight-forward code.

For small "optimizations" you can do safely without thinking, and which doesn't affect much the readability/maintability of the code, check out the "Premature Pessimization" section of the book *C++ Coding Standards* by Sutter & Alexandrescu.

For more optimization techniques, check out *Efficient C++* by Bulka & Mayhew. Only use when justified by profiling!

For good general C++ programming practices, check out:

- *C++ Coding Standards* by Sutter & Alexandrescu (must have, IMHO)
- *Effective C++/STL series* by Scott Meyers
- *Exceptional C++* series by Herb Sutter

Off the top of my head, one good general performance practice is to pass heavyweight objects by reference, instead of by copy. For example:

```
// Not a good idea, a whole other temporary copy of the (potentially big) vector will be created.
int sum(std::vector<int> v)
{
   // sum all values of v
   return sum;
}

// Better, vector is passed by constant reference
int sum(const std::vector<int>& v)
{
   // v is immutable ("read-only") in this context
   // sum all values of v.
   return sum;
}
```

For a small object like a complex number or 2-dimensional (x, y) point, the function will likely run faster with the object passed by copy.

When it comes to fixed-size, medium-weight objects, it's not so clear if the function will run faster with a copy or a reference to the object. Only profiling will tell. I usually just pass by const reference (if the function doesn't need a local copy) and only worry about it if profiling tells me to.

Some will say that you can inline small class methods without thinking. This may give you a runtime performance boost, but it may also lengthen your compile time if there is a heavy amount of inlining. If a class method is part of a library API, it might be better not to inline it, no matter how small it is. This is because the implementation of inline functions has to be visible to other modules/classes. If you change something in that inline function/method, then other modules that reference it need to be re-compiled.

When I first started to program, I would try to micro-optimize everything (that was the electrical engineer in me). What a waste of time!

If you're into embedded systems, then things change and you can't take memory for granted. But that's another whole can of worms.

Comment: Wow, I took too long to write that. It's aleady been covered by everyone!

Comment: This is called the "Fastest Gun in the West" (see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9731/fastest-gun-in-the-west-problem ). Here's how to beat it (Jon Skeet uses this methodology). Type up your basic, short answer as fast as possible and submit. This puts your answer up there and you are immediately eligible for votes. Then, go back and make edit(s) to your post until you are fully satisfied.

Comment: @Emile_Cormier ( Non-SO discussion : http://cantgrokwontgrok.blogspot.com/2008/09/stackoverflow-crackoverflow-or.html scroll to "Bob Munden Effect") Random-Aside : Yea you go girl! Show them men females can program too. 8- ]

Comment: @rib: Ahem... Emile is a French **masculine** name. The last 'e' is silent. Not to be confused with Emilie. :-)

Comment: Have you profiled passing by reference being slower than by value for smaller objects? I'd predict it can't be slower after compiler optimizations and maybe ever so slightly faster for read-only access since the data doesn't need copying and might alter the assembly to read directly from the allocated, small object.

Answer (score 6):

## Use the right container

### Sequence containers

- Do *not* use `vector` for data of unknown size if you are going to keep adding data to it. If you are going to repeatedly call `push_back()`, either use `reserve()` or use a `deque` instead.
- If you are going to be adding/removing data in the middle of the container, `list` is probably the right choice.
- If you are going to be adding/removing data from both ends of the container, `deque` is probably the right choice.
- If you need to access the nth element of the container, `list` is probably the wrong choice.
- If you need to both access the nth element of the container and add/remove elements in the middle, benchmark all three containers.
- If you have C++0x capability and are using a `list` but you never move backwards through the list, you may find `forward_list` more to your liking. It won't be faster but it will take up less space.

Note that this advice becomes more applicable the larger the container. For smaller containers, `vector` may always be the right choice simply because of the lower constant factors. When in doubt, benchmark.

### Associative containers

- If you do not have TR1, C++0x, or a vendor-specific `unordered_foo`/`hash_foo`, there isn't a ton of choice. Use whichever of the four containers is appropriate to your needs.
- If you do have an `unordered_foo`, use it instead of the ordered version if you do not care about the order of the elements and you have a good hash function for the type.

## Use exceptions judiciously

- Don't use exceptions in your normal code path. Save them for when you actually have an exceptional circumstance.

## Love templates

- Templates will cost you at compile time and space-wise, but the performance gains can be amazing if you have calculations that would otherwise be performed at run-time; sometimes even something so subtle as a downcast.

## Avoid `dynamic_cast`

- `dynamic_cast` is sometimes the only choice for doing something, but oftentimes the use of `dynamic_cast` can be eliminated by improving design.
- Don't replace `dynamic_cast` with a `typeid` followed by a `static_cast` either.

Comment: I agree with everything except the first point. `vector` grows exponentially, so the cost of not calling `reserve` before multiple calls to `push_back` is marginal. (It's still better to call `reserve` if you know the new size, but don't avoid using `vector` just because you don't). Also, `deque` won't be any better in this case.

Comment: The unordered associative containers are not necessarily faster.  If you have to rehash a lot (your profiler can tell you), they can be significantly slower.

Comment: @Mike Seymour: That is true of most implementations but not necessarily the case. While it's true that a `vector` insert is probably faster than a `deque` insert if you don't reallocate, the cost of reallocating a large `vector` is immense. Worse, it's concentrated at one time, so a very large `vector` may create a noticeable lag depending on the application.

Comment: I'd like to add to the first point; if your accessing more often than you add data to a container, std::vector is probably the right choice, even if deque, set, map or list seems more conveniant.

Comment: The advice about `std::vector` versus `std::deque` isn't a complete picture. Obviously the part about `std::vector::reserve` is fine if you know how many items will be added though. `std::vector` is faster at linear scans or any access pattern where you read or change data nearby each other. The complete picture includes all use - not just using `push_back` either a little or a lot. `std::deque` suffers from indirection as well as from the data not all being contiguous, meaning more cache misses in general.

Comment: The advice on exceptions can be strengthened. Use `noexcept` whenever possible as it signals to the compiler the extra code to unwind the stack and recover need not exist. It can also enable optimizations you may not know about. For example, `std::vector` uses a function called `move_if_noexcept` when shuffling objects around. As the name implies, you get a move if the move function is `noexcept`. Otherwise, you get an often painfully slow copy.

Answer (score 5):

Here is a nice article on the topic: [How To Go Slow](http://www.artima.com/cppsource/how_to_go_slow.html)

Answer (score 5):

Unless youre really sure another container type is better, use ´std::vector´. Even if ´std::deque, ´std::list´, ´std::map´ etc seems like more conveniant choices, a vector outperformes them both in memory usage and element access\iteration times.

Also, prefer using a containers member algorithm (ie ´map.equal_range(...)´) instead of thier global counterparts (´std::equal_range(begin(), end()...)´)

Comment: Memory is the cheapest resource. Unless you're coding something with strict memory needs, a container with a few extra pointers per element will not consume too much memory. `std::vector` can't be recommended over other containers without knowing the use case. Yes, `std::vector` is fastest at a linear scan or accessing nearby elements often. No, that doesn't mean never use `std::deque`, `std::list`, `std::map`, `std_unordered_map`, etc. A simple example is a need to add or remove elements throughout your container often while retaining order and duplicates, `std::list` will often work well.

Answer (score 5):

I like this question because it is asking for some "good habits". 
I have found that certain things that are desirable in programming are initially a chore, but become acceptable and even easy once they become habits.

One example is always using smart pointers instead of raw pointers to control heap memory lifetime. Another, related of course, is developing the habit of always using RAII for resource acquisition and release. Another is always using exceptions for error handling. 
These three tend to simplify code, thereby making it smaller and so faster, as well as easier to understand.

You could also make getters and setters implicitly inline; always make full use of initializer lists in constructors; and always use the find and other related functions that are provided in the std library, instead of crafting your own loops.

Not specifically C++, but it is often worthwhile to avoid data copying. In long-running programs with a lot of memory allocation it can be worthwhile to consider memory allocation as a major part of the design, so that the memory you use comes from pools that are reused, although this is not necessarily a common enough thing to be considered worthy of forming a habit.

One more thing - do not copy code from one place to another if you need the functionality - use a function. This keeps code size small and makes it easier to optimize all the places that use this functionality.

Comment: A good answer, but could use some paragraph breaks :)

Comment: I'll have to try to cultivate that habit.

Comment: I came back to look at this for some reason. So many paragraphs! Reminds me of the quote I read somewhere that the strongest urge to which mankind is prey, is the urge to correct someone else's draft.

Comment: Even Bjarne Stroustrup, the guy who added exceptions to the language, admits they are not as performant as alternatives such as error checking. If speed is the only goal, it's advisable to avoid exceptions altogether and to use `noexcept` to hint the code to unwind the stack and handle the exception need not be generated. Additionally, it can improve performance in other situations such as how `std::vector` uses `move_if_noexcept` when shuffling objects around. A move will be faster than a copy. It can have tremendous impact on performance.

Comment: How do you reckon a smart pointer will be faster than a raw pointer? The right design is a smart pointer, but it can never be faster than a raw pointer since the best case is the optimizer generates code that uses a raw pointer. I'm similarly not sure how RAII would be faster than running the same code outside the destructor. Again, the two methods ideally will be just as fast as each other, and it's better design to use RAII. However, RAII isn't a speed optimization.

Answer (score 4):

Templates! Using templates can reduce the amount of code because you can have a class or function/method that can be reusable with many datatypes.

Consider the following:

```
#include <string>
using std::basic_string;

template <class T>
    void CreateString(basic_string<T> s)
    {
        //...
    }
```

The basic_string could be composed of char, wchar_t, unsigned char or unsigned wchar_t.

Templates could also be used for a panoply of different things such as traits, class specialization or even used to pass a int value to a class!

Comment: Templates may also cause code-bloat, since they are code stencils.  The compiler will generate similar code for each data type.

Comment: and code bloat can cause cache misses, which is the chief way that it interferes with performance.

Comment: "Templates may also cause code-bloat ..." - The same can be said about non-template code.  In both cases it all depends on how you use/implement the code in question.

Comment: @Thomas Matthews: Using templates will for sure take more time at compilation but will be faster at execution.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews If you need that code, you're either going to have to write it for each type you want it for or write one template. There should be no code bloat. The process can, however, increase compile time as more stuff must be done.

Answer (score 3):

Avoid iterating over the same dataset multiple times as much as possible.

Answer (score 3):

[**This page sum up all you have to know about optimization in C++ (be it while or after writing software).**](http://www.tantalon.com/pete/cppopt/main.htm) It's really good advice and is very lear -- and can be used as a useful reminder in optimization phase on a project.

It's a bit old so you also have to know wich optimizations are already done by your compiler (like NRVO).

Other than that, reading the Effective C++, More Effective C++, Effective STL and C++ Coding Standards that have already been cited is important too, because it explains a lot of things about what occurs in the language and in the STL, allowing you to better optimize your specific case by using a better understanding of what's happening exactly.

Comment: The most comprehensive link up to now

Answer (score 2):

Here's a list I've referred to in the past - http://www.devx.com/cplus/Article/16328/0/page/1. Beyond that, Googling c++ performance tips yields quite a bit.

Answer (score 2):

I took the habit to prefer writing `++i` rather than `i++` not that it brings any performance boost when `i` is an `int` but things are different when `i` is an `iterator` which might have a complex implementation.

Then let's say you come from the C programming language, lose your habit to declare all your variables at the beginning on the function: declare your variables when they are needed in the function flow since the function might contain early `return` statements before some variables that were initialized at the beginning are effectively used.

Apart from that, another resource is [C++ Coding Standards: 101 Rules, Guidelines, and Best Practices](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321113586) by Herb Sutter (him again) and Alexei Alexandrescu.

There is also a more recent edition of Scott Meyers' Effective C++: [Effective C++: 55 specific ways to improve your programs and designs](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321334876).

Finally, I would like to mention Tony Albrecht's [Pitfalls of Object Oriented Programming](http://research.scee.net/files/presentations/gcapaustralia09/Pitfalls%5Fof%5FObject%5FOriented%5FProgramming%5FGCAP%5F09.pdf) presentation: not that it contains rules of thumb you can follow blindly but it's a very interesting read.

Comment: Having many returns in one function can be problematic...

Comment: maybe I chose a poor example, but the point is to declare variables and initialize them only at the point when they are used, not 200 lines above -- now you can argue that 200 lines long functions can be problematic ;)

Comment: I'd say for the most cases that it doesn't matter. Generally many of these small optimizations are more destructive in the development process than they are useful. The modern compilers can easily find out how to delay initialization of variables until they are used. The most important thing is to keep the code clean and simple (readable).

Comment: "The modern compilers can easily find out how to delay initialization of variables until they are used." - compilers cannot rearrange initializations when the latter cause observable side effects. One particular case of an observable side effect is memory allocation using `new` (consider overloaded operator etc), so if a constructor of some class calls `new` at any point, it usually won't be delay-initialized.

Comment: Initialization and declaration of variables should be nearby the use of them for readability. It might be faster in some cases such as an early `return`, but it will usually be the same as usually the entire logic of a function runs before `return`. Not an incorrect micro optimization though. @TommyAndersen Which kinds of optimizations do you mean? The big ones like passing by constant reference increase readability by coding intent. I'm also not aware that compilers reorder initializations. Do you have a source for that?

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest to read chapter II ("Performance") of ["Programming Pearls"](http://www.cs.bell-labs.com/cm/cs/pearls/) from Jon Bentley. It's not C++ specific, but those techniques can be applied in C or C++ as well. The website contains just parts from the book, I recommend to read the book.

Answer (score 1):

Lots of good suggestions here already.

One of the best ways to get into good habits is to force them on yourself. For this I love PC-Lint. PC-Lint will actually enforce Scott Meyer's Effective C++ & More Effective C++ rules. Also obeying Lint rules tends to lead to easier to maintain, less error-prone, and cleaner code. Just don't go too crazy when you realize lint will often generate more output than you have source code; I once worked on a project with 150MB of source code and 1.8GB of Lint messages.

Answer (score 1):

1. Avoid memory fragmentation.
2. Aligned memory.
3. SIMD instructions.
4. Lockless multithreading.
5. Use proper acceleration trees, such as kd-tree, cover tree, octree, quadtree, etc. 
   5a. Define these in ways that allow for the first three (ie make nodes all in one block)
6. inlining. The lowest hanging but quite delicious fruit.

The performance boosts you can get this way are astonishing. For me 1500 times for a computation heavy app. Not over brute fore, but over similar data structures written in a major software package.

I'd not bother with stuck like preincrement over post. That only gives savings in certains (unimportant) cases and most of what's mentioned is similar stuff that might scrape out an extra 1% here and there once in a while but usually isn't worth the bother.

Comment: Keep in mind that concurrency needs the threads to be launched and needs the work to be divided, both of which take time. A sequential algorithm will outperform a parallelized one for quite some time. It only becomes worth it when the amount of work to do is large enough (some combination of the quantity of work to do and its complexity). For example, I have found `Collection::stream` is faster than `Collection::parallelStream` for many datasets in Java due to that initial work to parallelize the operation.

Answer (score 1):

This one will have very good Techniques for general c++ Optimization:

http://www.tantalon.com/pete/cppopt/main.htm

Use the profiler to see what part of application running slowly and then use the optimizing techniques.

I used the valgrind with callgrind tool for the profiling purpose and it will give you which lines cost how much.

valgrind --tool=callgrind

Answer (score 0):

The best way to improve these skills is reading books and articles, but I can help you with some tips:

- 1- Accept Objects by reference and Primitive or Pointer Types by value but use object pointer if a function stores a reference or a pointer to the object.
- 2- Don't use MACROS to declare constants -> use static const.
- 3- Always implement a virtual destructor if your class may be subclassed.

Comment: why not to use Macros? i thoght those are a compile thing and should be the fastest therefore, no? and what's the idea behind the virtual destructor? this will automatically add a vft pointer even if it's not needed, no?

Comment: There are good reasons to avoid macros and implement virtual destructors when you need them, but they have nothing to do with performance.

Comment: 1- A "#define is expanded by the preprocessor while constants are processed by the compiler and are included in the symbolic information used to debug the code.

2- If your class will be subclassed declare a destructor virtual to properly destroy derived objects thought base pointers.

Comment: 2 and 3 look like good ideas, but I don't see how they relate to performance.

Comment: @MikeSeymour A virtual function adds a vft pointer and a step of indirection when calling that function. Some people even use certain designs to avoid virtual functions such as the curiously recurring template pattern. It can affect performance greatly if the functions in question are frequently called. You're half right though as adding virtual isn't going to increase speed.

Answer (score 0):

- Avoid multiple inheritance.
- Use virtuals when they are necessary, not just for fun
- Use templated collection classes only when it's a pain not to

Comment: Multiple inheritance should not necessarily be avoided. That is a belief that comes from Java, C# and probably some other languages that has the philosophy of limiting what a programmer may do for security. If you know what you are doing in C++ there is nothing wrong with it.

Comment: why avoiding multiple inheritance? and what's the problem with templated collection (except for the data overhead compared to a simple array)

Comment: Multiple inheritance can have a small impact on performance, as the `this` pointer sometimes needs to be adjusted to point to different base classes, and member functions are sometimes called through wrappers. But it's certainly not enough to warrant influencing how you design your class hierarchy.

Comment: @Partial Languages like Java prohibit multiple inheritance in pursuits of reducing common programming errors. Similar design goals were there when they didn't include operator overloading and when they made everything an object reference passed by value (other than primitives although they are passed by value too). I could write pages about the intentional simplifications in Java over C++. The philosophy wasn't about security. To offset the limitation introduced, they added interfaces to "inherit" multiple behaviors.

Answer (score 0):

Why nobody mentioned it so far? Why is everyone into poor little `++i`?

One of the best little things you can easily do, to *not pessimize* your code:

**Effective C++** *by Scott Meyers*, Item 20:

**Prefer pass-by-reference-to-const to pass-by value**

Example:

```
// this is a better option
void some_function(const std::string &str);
// than this:
void some_function(std::string str);
```

In case of short `std::string` you might not win much, but passing *big* objects like that, can save you quite a lot of computing power as you avoid redundant copying. And can also save you from a bug or two if you forgot to implement your copy constructor.

Comment: Oh, stupid me, Kristo has recommended it already.