# What are the solutions to increase the speed of the program in C ++?

Tags: c++

What are the solutions to increase the speed of the program in C ++?
My program is very slow and I want to increase the speed

Comment: Seems a duplicate of this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2030189/general-c-performance-improvement-tips

Comment: Without knowing anything about your program it's hard to give advice.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [General C++ Performance Improvement Tips](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2030189/general-c-performance-improvement-tips)

Comment: The subject of a wikipedia page: [program optimization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Program_optimization). Note this sentence (by Donald Knuth): *premature optimization is the root of all evil*

Comment: a very common cause for slow execution is forgetting to turn on compiler optimizations. Often that is all you need

Comment: Avoid accessing the hard disk.

Answer (score 1):

Here are some tips you can use to speed up any program:

- Do memoizing/caching - instead of calculating the same value over and over again, save it and simply recall it from memory later.
- Do batch IO - instead of writing/reading character by character or line by line, store them in memory and then read/write a bunch of characters or lines at the same time.
- Use faster algorithms - instead of using brute force, use tree search, use dictionaries/hashes/array indices for faster access. Aim for smaller values of big-o.