# C/C++ Optimizations

Tags: c++, c, compiler-construction

I've been raised in a very OO manner when it comes to programming, which has unfortunately meant that highly optimized code is not my forte.  I'm fairly good at C now and can usually do things in reasonably intelligent ways, but I still have trouble thinking of the most optimized way to handle situations.

One example would be:

```
int strlen(const char* str)
{
    char* s;
    for (s=str; *s; ++s);
    return s-str;
}
```

I would never have thought of that myself.

So, what are some good resources that expose you to optimized code like this?  I'd like to find a place where I could read up on the theory behind it, what the compiler does in the background which makes it worthwhile, etc.

It would also be nice if some resources were noted for studying optimized data structures with application to real-life scenarios, but that's probably too much to ask.

Comment: In what way is that code optimized beyond the trivial version of  `int count=0; while(str++) count++; return count;`?

Comment: @Stargazer712 the version in the Q has half as many arithmetic operations

Comment: That code is not optimised, it's obfuscated.

Comment: Your best tool for optimization is a good profiler.  Unless you're measuring performance gains your just guessing and more than likely you'll guess the wrong parts to optimize.

Comment: @Stargazer712, in your example, you are performing two increments. In an insanely massive string there could be a measurable performance difference.

Comment: If I knew that for sure I wouldn't be asking the question, but apparently its more optimized from what I've been told.  Either way, it's just my example, I want a good book/site on optimizations in general and on how to "think fast".  I always thought I did at work until I started cross-interviewing to good finance places.

Comment: optimized for expanding maintenance budgets?

Comment: Though the example is perhaps not a great one, I think the question is a very good one, and I would be curious if people could recommend good resources for learning about low-level optimization of C and C++ code.

Comment: @David Heffernan, that's creative. Both are still O(n), but on small strings (which are probably more common) I can definitely see the benefit.

Comment: @Stargazer O(n) yes, but with a factor of 2 difference in op count! O(2n) == O(n)

Comment: It has one fewer increments per iteration, which is significant considering how little work is done in the loop.

Comment: @Stargazer712, but in this case it's not a question of both being O(N), one loop could be doing extra work even though it's cost per iteration is constant. Quite simply, more CPU instructions would be executed. Isn't that correct?

Comment: I haven't measured the performance, but the compiler uses fewer instructions to implement Stargazer712's suggestion (gcc with -O2).

Comment: possible duplicate of [C++ Optimization Techniques](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/653980/c-optimization-techniques)

Comment: @Lex - What about high level optimizations? Wouldn't that get us more? Like std::string storing its length, so it doesn't have to call strlen at all.

Comment: Have a look at Scotts talk about Cache hits http://scottmeyers.blogspot.com/2011/05/videos-from-accu-talks-now-available.html

Comment: @Peter, I totally understand what you guys are saying (and thank you for that--I'm wiser because of it). I was just restating what my initial source of confusion was when I said both are O(n)

Comment: This is an interesting question. Voting to reopen

Comment: @omrib: That could be because it has a bug (it doesn't dereference the pointer).

Comment: @zdan: I've fixed that bug, but actually introduced another. The latest version is still in favour of Stargazer712 (by one instruction). The point is that on a different compiler it could be different, I suggest calling the standard strlen which would be faster than either versions (or would it?! measure twice, optimise once).

Comment: The actual implementation of the `strlen` function in the CRT is much faster. Here is a good resource: http://www.hackersdelight.org/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't try too hard with micro optimizations. With modern day compilers it is best to let optimizations like those get handled by the compiler. It is better to spend your time choosing the right algorithms, and design patterns for your applications. Find a decent profiler and learn how to use it. Don't waste your time trying to figure out how to optimize `strlen`.

As for references in how to do these micro optimizations I have mentioned it before, but will gladly do so again, Agner's guide is simply outstanding, and free :) Check out: http://www.agner.org/optimize/ there should be plenty of guides.

BTW: The most optimised version of `strlen` I've come across is made by Agner: http://www.agner.org/optimize/asmlib-instructions.pdf and is written in assembly. ;-)

Comment: I partially agree. It's true that it's better _optimize_ your time choosing algorithms and patterns, but in my opinion a good programmer should think about the code he's writing. It's useless throw up 10 lines of code when just 5 are needed (that's not the case of strlen, obviously).

Comment: True, but most of the time any modern compiler will save you, and when people ask for optimizations and show `strlen` as an example, you know they are asking for all the wrong reasons.

Comment: I also slightly disagree. While generally correct, there are instances where code can introduce constraints that can prevent certain optimizations from being applied. Whenever a programmer is building a loop, they should always be thinking about how many operations per iteration will be incurred (it's really not too hard). In many cases, an extra function call inside a loop is beyond compiler optimization because of side-effects; it's really up to the programmer to know this.

Answer (score 1):

[What every programmer should know about memory, Part 1](http://lwn.net/Articles/250967/) is one resource which was interesting.  It gets into a lot of the stupid low level details.

One of the *major* points of optimization is code size though.  If you leverage intelligent OO design, small design, you are optimizing.  I personally believe ignoring the small details and focusing on the high level will get you further in speed and in *your career*.  Besides, gprof is better at it than you ever will be.