# Best way to exchange values of two integers?

Tags: performance, integer

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the fastest way to swap values in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36906/what-is-the-fastest-way-to-swap-values-in-c)

I need to exchange values of two integers (for example x and y)
This is the simplest way:

```
int temp = x;
x = y;
y = temp;
```

and I also found a better way:

```
x = x + y;
y = x - y;
x = x - y;
```

Is there a better way to increase performance?

Comment: There is **no possible way** that *either* of these pieces of code is a bottleneck in your application.

Comment: Unless you're asking this out of curiosity, you're wasting effort. Trust your compiler to produce efficient code for such a trivial operation.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the fastest way to swap values in C?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36906/what-is-the-fastest-way-to-swap-values-in-c), [Swap the values of two variables without using third variable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/756750/swap-the-values-of-two-variables-without-using-third-variable), [Swap two variables without using a temp variable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/804706/swap-two-variables-without-using-a-temp-variable), *etc. etc. etc.*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

it is posible with **XOR** "**^**" operator:

```
  a = a^b;
  b = a^b;
  a = a^b;
```

Comment: yes, XOR is faster than + operator.Thank you.

Comment: @Ademiban: Quote from wiki "Most modern compilers can optimize away the temporary variable in the naive swap, in which case the naive swap uses the same amount of memory and the same number of registers as the XOR swap and is at least as fast, and often faster."

Comment: I dont know )) I have x=5 y=3 after that x is 0, y is 5.in Java

Comment: @Ademiban No way! check again with different values. :))

Comment: :D it's wrong way if it works wrong for at least one case.

Answer (score 2):

Well in the second option you use 2 variables instead of 3 in the 1st option, this means you allocate less memory.

Comment: yes and I wanna know is there a better way? say, do it with two operators.