# Can't sort array without temp variable using pointer

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

The algorithm to swap the values of two integers `x` and `y` without using a `tmp` variable is

```
x = x + y;
y = x - y;
x = x - y;
```

I've written a code to sort an array by passing it to a method. The method accepts the array in a pointer `*ptr`. Thus, the elements of the array, `arr[0], arr[1],...` would be accessed with the pointer variable as `*(ptr + 0), *(ptr + 1),...`. However, the problem I'm facing is that when I try to swap the values of the array while sorting by referencing the memory location with a pointer, without the use of a temporary variable, the array is not getting sorted the way I expect and, instead, I see some random elements getting inserted into the array.

This is my array sorting code *(selection sort - the sort algorithm is correct)*:

```
void sort(int *arr, int n){
    int i,j,m;
    for(i=0; i<n-1; i++){
        m = i;
        for(j=i+1; j<n; j++){
            if(arr[j] < arr[m])
                m = j;
        }
        //swapping arr[i] and arr[m]
        *(arr + i) = *(arr + i) + *(arr + m);
        *(arr + m) = *(arr + i) - *(arr + m);
        *(arr + i) = *(arr + i) - *(arr + m);
    }
    //print the array...
}

void main(){
    int arr[] = {2,4,3,5,8,7};
    sort(arr, 6);
}
```

**INPUT**:

```
2 4 3 5 8 7
```

**EXPECTED OUTPUT**:

```
2 3 4 5 7 8
```

**OBTAINED OUTPUT**:

```
0 3 0 0 7 8
```

**Why is this happening? What am I doing wrong?**

Comment: How do you call the function? Where is your [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I've added the main method and shown how I call the sort method

Comment: Why are you trying to swap without using a temporary?  This is kind of like trying to drive nails without using a hammer -- you can do it if you really want to, but simply using a hammer (or, in this case, a temporary variable) is far, far easier, and almost invariably better.

Comment: @SteveSummit Honestly, just trying out random stuff; exploring C.

Comment: Although unlikely, the `x = x + y` code can theoretically overflow.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44344453/is-this-way-is-prefered-to-swap-two-variable-without-temp-in-c ,

Comment: @SteveSummit I've had the overflow thing in mind but then it doesn't really cause a problem while dealing with signed numbers. I tried with `x = 32767; y = 1` and also `x = -32768; y = -12`. It worked. But in the case of unsigned numbers, I'd definitely use a temp variable because people have said on the question you linked that discarding a temp variable gives no significant memory advantage.

Comment: @progyammer As it happens, it'll always work on unsigned numbers, where "wraparound" behavior on over/underfllow is guaranteed bu the C Standard.  Strictly speaking, that wraparound behavior is *not* guaranteed for signed numbers (although it does typically work as you expect on the vast majority of machines).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> The algorithm to swap the values of two integers x and y without using a tmp variable is
>
> ```
> x = x + y;
> y = x - y;
> x = x - y;
> ```

One of several problems with this approach is that it does not work when `x` and `y` expressions refer to the same memory location. This is exactly what happens when an item is in its place after completion of the nested loop, i.e. when `i` is the same as `m`.

Adding `if (i == m) continue` before going into the swap will fix this problem.

[Demo.](https://ideone.com/lXH3l5)

Comment: @progyammer Since this is a general algo, `x` and `y` are treated more generically as expressions, not as variables. For example, in your case `*(arr + i)` expression takes place of `x`, and `*(arr + m)` takes place of `y`.

Comment: I totally understood what you said.

Comment: Basically, in C, the situation you mentioned takes the form of `x = x + x; x = x - x; x = x - x;`, right?

Comment: @progyammer Yes, that's the way to do it with C variables.

Comment: But again, how does this work when I use `arr[i]` instead of `*(arr + i)`??

Comment: @daslinkenlight Oops! My bad. It obviously doesn't. You've been an excellent explainer.