# Swap sub-arrays of a multi-dimensional array in C

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, gcc

I have a 50 x 50 matrix `arr[50][50]` and need to swap the values in the sub-array `arr[0]` and `arr[1]`.
ie, the whole 50 elements in each sub-array need to be swapped.

The only way I can think of to do this is by using a loop like:

```
for(i=0; i<50; ++i)
{
    int t = arr[0][i];
    arr[0][i] = arr[1][i];
    arr[1][i] = t;
}
```

I was wondering if there were any simpler or shorter methods? Using pointers maybe?

I tried things like

```
int *t = arr[0];
arr[0] = arr[1];
arr[1] = t;
```

but it gave error at the first line about "incompatible types when assigning to type 'int[2]' from type 'int *' ".

Then I tried pointer to an array

```
int (*t)[50] = arr[0];
arr[0] = arr[1];
arr[1] = t;
```

This time I got error at the second line about "incompatible types when assigning to type 'int[50]' from type 'int *' ".

Comment: Well a faster way would be to use xor expression instead of using a third variable - `arr[0][i] = arr[0][i]^arr[1][i]; arr[1][i] = arr[0][i]^arr[1][i]; arr[0][i] = arr[0][i]^arr[1][i];`, The complexity would be the same but the constant factors change.

Comment: The only way you can copy data with the `=` is from a simple variable, a single array element, or a `struct`. Consider using `int temp[50]` and `memcpy`.

Comment: You will need to copy the rows (or swap them). You can use something like `int tmp[50];` then `memcpy (tmp, arr[0], 50 * sizeof *tmp); memcpy (arr[0], arr[1], 50 * sizeof *arr[0]); memcpy (arr[1], tmp, 50 * sizeof *arr[1]);`

Comment: @GAURANG VYAS: Quite the oppoosite. The *faster* way would be not to obfuscate the code and help the compiler to figure out that you just want to swap two values. Your XOR trick is a notorious anti-pattern that has to be avoided.

Comment: @AnT can you explain more ?

Comment: @GAURANGVYAS the OP's swap loop does 3 reads and 3 writes in each iteration (apart from `i`) but your way does 6 reads and 3 writes.

Comment: @GAURANG VYAS: A simple swap with a third variable will be immediately recognized by a decent compiler as a swap operation. The compiler will be able to implement it in the most efficient way: maybe a single XCHNG instruction, maybe even your XOR trick, maybe something else. Compilers are better at such micro-optimizations. Meanwhile, your XOR trick might just confuse the compiler and impede these optimizations.

Comment: Regarding the swap trick: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36906/what-is-the-fastest-way-to-swap-values-in-c

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your matrix is implemented as `arr[50][50]` then the only way to physically swap two rows is to physically exchange data in memory. Your cycle is one way to do it. The rest would be just variations of that approach. You can swap matrix elements one-by-one (your cycle), you can swap the entire rows using an intermediate row-sized buffer (`memcpy` approach). All of them still do the same thing. There's no way around it.

If your array were implemented differently - say, a "jagged" array implemented as array of *pointers* to sub-arrays, then you would be able to just swap two pointers and be done with it. But in case of `arr[50][50]` it is not possible.

If you wish, you can just "convert" your current array into a "jagged" version by a separate row-pointer array. That row-pointer array will now become your matrix `a`, while the original `a[50][50]` will become `a_data`

```
int a_data[50][50];

int *a[50];
for (unsigned i = 0; i < 50; ++i)
  a[i] = a_data[i];

/* Fill the matrix */
for (unsigned i = 0; i < 50; ++i)
  for (unsigned j = 0; j < 50; ++j)
    a[i][j] = rand();

/* Print the matrix */
for (unsigned i = 0; i < 50; ++i)
{
  for (unsigned j = 0; j < 50; ++j)
    printf("%d ", a[i][j]);
  printf("\n");
}

/* Swap the rows */
int *temp = a[0];
a[0] = a[1];
a[1] = temp;

/* Print the matrix */
for (unsigned i = 0; i < 50; ++i)
{
  for (unsigned j = 0; j < 50; ++j)
    printf("%d ", a[i][j]);
  printf("\n");
}
```

Note, that despite the physical structure of `a` is now different, you can still use `a[i][j]` syntax to work with it.

Answer (score 1):

As explained in the comments, and within the other answers, in order to swap rows of an actual 2D array (as apposed to an array of pointers), you must copy/move the data from the source to target row in memory. The most straight forward way to approach this is either with a loop to copy element-by-element to temporary storage to effect the swap, or use the memory copy functions provided by the C-library (e.g. `memcpy` or `memmove`). A simple implementation using `memcopy` (shown with a `3x10` array for array for purposes of the example) would be:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

enum { ROW = 3, COL = 10 };

void swaprow (int (*a)[COL], int c1, int c2);
void prna (int (*a)[COL]);

int main (void) {

    int a[ROW][COL] = {{0}};

    for (int i = 0; i < ROW; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < COL; j++)
            a[i][j] = i;

    prna (a);
    swaprow (a, 0, 1);
    putchar ('\n');
    prna (a);

    return 0;
}

void swaprow (int (*a)[COL], int c1, int c2)
{
    int tmp[COL];

    memcpy (tmp, a[c1], COL * sizeof *tmp);
    memcpy (a[c1], a[c2], COL * sizeof *a[c1]);
    memcpy (a[c2], tmp, COL * sizeof *a[c2]);
}

void prna (int (*a)[COL])
{
    for (int i = 0; i < ROW; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < COL; j++)
            printf ("%2d", a[i][j]);
        putchar ('\n');
    }

}
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/array2d_swap_row
 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2

 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2
```

Look things over and let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Thanks for the example!

Answer (score 0):

You will have to copy the data to be swapped with `memcpy`, I have provided sample to program to show how you can do it(ie swap arr[0] and arr[1]).

```
int main(void) {
    // your code goes here
    int t[3];
    int arr[3][3]={{1,2,3},{4,5,6},{7,8,9}};
    printf("\n%d %d %d",arr[0][0],arr[0][1],arr[0][2]);
    printf("\n%d %d %d",arr[1][0],arr[1][1],arr[1][2]);
    memcpy(t,arr[0],sizeof(t));
    memcpy(arr[0],arr[1],sizeof(t));
    memcpy(arr[1],t,sizeof(t));
    printf("\n%d %d %d",arr[0][0],arr[0][1],arr[0][2]);
    printf("\n%d %d %d",arr[1][0],arr[1][1],arr[1][2]);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @weather Vane, True I had earlier originally taken 4 * 4 matrix, corrected it now

Comment: Thanks for the example