# unexpected output for rerverse array element using pointer

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I want to reverse an array element using pointer But
why i getting out-put as 4 3 3 4
when i  give input 1 2 3 4

here my code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    int n, a[100], *ptr;
    printf("enter array size: ");   
    scanf("%d",&n);
    printf("enter array element: ");
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        scanf("%d",&a[i]);
    }

    ptr = &a[0];
    int j=0;
    int i = n-1;

    while(j != n)
    {   
        a[j] = *(ptr+i);
        j++;
        i--;
    }

    // for printing output

    printf("\nin reverse: \n");
    for(int k=0; k<n; k++)
    {
        printf("%d, ",a[k]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

can anybody tell me what is the problem here ?

Comment: Can you tell me why you think that code should reverse an array?

Comment: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: Just take a paper sheet and a pencil, and follow the algo *by hand*. The cause will be self evident (a[1] and a[0] have already been changed when you use them).

Answer (score 2):

```
while(j != n)
{   
    a[j] = *(ptr+i);
    j++;
    i--;
}
```

This isn't actually swapping the two values. It's simple setting the first half. In order to swap them you'd add a line like:

```
while(j != n / 2)
{   
    int temp = a[j];
    a[j] = *(ptr+i);
    *(ptr + i) = temp;
    j++;
    i--;
}
```

Comment: Hmm, if you use swapping (which is good here) you only need to process half of the array...

Comment: Ah, yeah I forgot you need to change n. Also you should be using a for loop for this

Comment: Chuckling... yes, it's a real shocker to swap over the full array only to end up right back where you started `:)`

Answer (score -1):

In your code you are overwriting the values..

In order to reverse numbers in place by using pointers, replace the `while-loop` as below in your code.

```
int* ptr_start = a;
int* ptr_end = a + (sizeof(a) / sizeof(a[0])) - 1;
 while (ptr_start < ptr_end) {
        *ptr_end   ^= *ptr_start;
        *ptr_start ^= *ptr_end ;
        *ptr_end   ^= *ptr_start;
        ptr_start++;
        ptr_end--;
      }
```

**Note:** There will be an -ve impact on performance.

Comment: Instead just mark negative, have patience to put a comment, so that will help some one.. Read question and my answer.. suggest why it's not right answer

Comment: Your answer is needlessly complex for his solution, and is inefficient

Comment: @MatthewKerian i don't think the question talks about efficiency and more over he want achieve with pointers. In that context is the solution is wrong ?

Comment: If I asked you the directions to a restaraunt down the street would you take me all over the place? For arrays you're always using pointers

Comment: @MatthewKerian off-course yes if all the roads blocked or customer wants. Is that the crime ??

Comment: Except in this case there was a wide open rode he wanted to take that you ignored. The other answer posted solves it much cleaned while also being more efficient

Comment: that Edited with note, but if you don't know `xor operation`, it means is not cleaner ??

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36906/what-is-the-fastest-way-to-swap-values-in-c

Comment: That's comes when efficiency matters not the methods to explore.